# QT QOpenGLWidget : how to modify individual vertices values in VBO without using data block copy?

Tags: c++, qt, opengl, vbo

I don't know if it is possible or not:

- I have an array of QVector3D vertices that I copy to a VBO
- sometimes I want to modify only the z value of a range of vertices between the values (x1, y1) and (x2, y2) - the concerned vertices strictly follow each other
- my "good" idea is to only modify the z values with a direct access to the VBO.

I have searched a lot, but all the solutions I saw use memcpy, something like this :

```
m_vboPos.bind();
GLfloat* PosBuffer = (GLfloat*) (m_vboPos.map(QOpenGLBuffer::WriteOnly));
if (PosBuffer != (GLfloat*) NULL) {
    memcpy(PosBuffer, m_Vertices.constData(), m_Vertices.size() * sizeof(QVector3D));
m_vboPos.unmap();
m_vboPos.release();
```

But it is to copy *blocks* of data.

I don't think using memcpy to change only 1 float value in every concerned vertex would be very efficient (I have several millions of vertices in the VBO).

I'd just like to optimize because copying millions of vertices takes a (too) long time : is there a way to achieve my goal (without memcpy ?), for only one float here and there ? (already tried that but couldn't make it, I must be missing something)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This call here

> ```
> GLfloat* PosBuffer = (GLfloat*) (m_vboPos.map(QOpenGLBuffer::WriteOnly));
> ```

will internally call [`glMapBuffer`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glMapBuffer.xhtml) which means that it just maps the buffer contents into the address space of your process (see also the [OpenGL Wiki on Buffer Object Mapping](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Buffer_Object#Mapping).

Since you map it write-only, you can simply overwrite each and every bit of the buffer, as you see fit. There is no need to use `memcpy`, you can just use any means to write to  memory, e.g. you can directly do

```
PosBuffer[3*vertex_id + 2] = 42.0f; // assuming 3 floats per vertex
```

> I don't think using `memcpy` to change only 1 float value in every concerned vertex would be very efficient (I have several millions of vertices in the VBO).

Yes, doing a million separate `memcpy()` calls for 4 bytes each will not be a good idea. A modern compiler might actually inline it, so it might be equivalent to just individual assignments, though. But you can also do the assignments directly, since `memcpy` is not gaining you anything here.

However, it is not clear what the performance impacts of all this are. `glMapBuffer` might return a pointer to

- some local copy of the VBO in system memory, and will have later to copy the contents to the GPU. Since it does not know which values you changed and which not, it might have to re-transmit the whole buffer.
- some system meory inside the GART area, which is mapped on the GPU, so the GPU will directly access this memory when reading from the buffer.
- some I/O-mapped region in VRAM. In this case, the caching behavior of the memory region might be significantly different, and changing a 4 bytes in every 12 byte block might not be the most ideal approach. Just re-copying the whole sub-block as one big junk might yield better performance.

The mapping itself is also not for free, it involves changing the page tables, and the GL driver might have to synchronize it's threads, or, in the worst case, synchronize with the GPU (to prevent you from overwriting stuff the GPU is still using for a previous draw call which is still in flight).

> sometimes I want to modify only the z value of a range of vertices between the values (x1, y1) and (x2, y2) - the concerned vertices strictly follow each other

So you have a continuous sub-region of the buffer which you want to modify. I would recommend to look at two alternatives:

1. Use  [`glMapBufferRange`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glMapBufferRange.xhtml) (if available in your OpenGL version) to map only the region you care about.
2. Forget about buffer mapping completely, and try [`glBufferSubData()`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glBufferSubData.xhtml). Not individually on each `z` component of each vertex, but as one big junk for the whole range of modified vertices. This will imply you have a local copy of the buffer contents in your memory somewhere, just update in, and send the results to the GL.

Which option is better will depend on a lot of different factors, and I would not rule one of them out without benchmarking in the actual scenario, on the actual implementations you care about. Also have a look at the general strategies for [Buffer Object Streaming in OpenGL](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Buffer_Object_Streaming). A [persistently mapped buffer](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Buffer_Object#Persistent_mapping) might or might not be also a good option for your use case.

Answer (score 1):

The glMap method works great and is really FAST !

Thanks a lot genpfault, the speed gain is so great that the 3D rendering isn't choppy anymore.

Here is my new code, simplified to offer an easy to understand answer :

```
vertexbuffer.bind();
GLfloat* posBuffer = (GLfloat*) (vertexbuffer.map(QOpenGLBuffer::WriteOnly));

if (posBuffer != (GLfloat*) NULL) {
    int index = NumberOfVertices(area.y + 1, image.cols); // index of first vertex on line area.y
    for (row = ...) for (col = ...) {
        if (mask.at<uchar>(row, col) != 0)
            posBuffer[3 * index + 2] = depthmap.at<uchar>(row, col) * depth;
        index++;
    }
}
vertexbuffer.unmap();
vertexbuffer.release();
```